# Get textbox value in user form from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an user form that displays textbox with current path to shared Excel workbook.
[image: User Form with textbox]

It is used in many macros to get workbook's path (using line `UserForm1.TextBox1.Value`)

The textbox itself has Activate Event, that displays data from cell (user can change cell value if they move shared workbook somewhere)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   TextBox1.Value = Workbooks("personal.xlsb").Worksheets("sheet").range("A2").Value

End Sub
```

But even when textbox displays correct value, it's value in properties stays the same as it was when it was created. It doesn't update. How it looks in VBA editor:

[image: Editor]

So whenever user updates the path, textbox displays correct path, but all macros using it still point to the original value.

Is it possible to save textbox displayed value also in the properties?

Comment: Use `activeworkbook`, if you have the code in the personal workbook, but changing the value in a different workbook, you need to specify that workbook.

Comment: @Davesexcel, I am sorry, but where should I use `ActiveWorkbook`? As far as I know, this line doesn't have user form or textbox properties

Comment: I think @Davesexcel means to replace `Workbooks("personal.xlsb").` with `ActiveWorkbook`. Also, have you tried using `TextBox1.Text` instead of `TextBox1.Value`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I tried both `.Text` and `.Value` - nothing works. `ActiveWorkbook` gives `Subscript out of range` error. Textbox displays correct value, but value in properties is still the original one even when it is not referring to cell value, but it is changed by command button and input box

Answer (score 0):

> it's value in properties stays the same

> Is it possible to save> textbox displayed value also in the
> properties?

I actually can't grasp the meaning of "properties"

so here's a blind shot

add:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Workbooks("personal.xlsb").Worksheets("sheet").Range("A2").Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

BTW, you should also make sure your "personal.xlsb" workbook actually has a worksheet named after "Sheet"